# StreamCorruptedException and ObjectInputStream|FileInputStream

Tags: android, stream, fileinputstream, objectinputstream

After creating a backup of my shared preference `xml` file(programmatically) and saving into external storage, I created a method for restoring it, by reading data with `ObjectInputStream` and `FileInputStream` from that xml file, and then put data back in app's shared preference.

This is how I'm restoring data:

```
public void restoreFAV(Context context) {
    File src = new File(storagePath+PREFS_NAME+".xml");
    ObjectInputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(src));
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEdit =
                      context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        Log.d("Pref Restore prefEdit",prefEdit.toString());
        prefEdit.clear();
        Log.d("Pref Restore prefEdit",prefEdit.toString());

        Map<String, ?> entries = (Map<String, ?>) input.readObject();
        Log.d("Pref Restore entries",entries.toString());

        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : entries.entrySet()) {
            Object v = entry.getValue();
            Log.d("Pref Restore Object v",v.toString());
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Log.d("Pref Restore String key", key);
            prefEdit.putString(key, ((String) v));
        }
        prefEdit.apply();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (input != null) {
                input.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting `StreamCorruptedException` exception.

```
08-20 18:42:44.228: W/System.err(28802): java.io.StreamCorruptedException
08-20 18:42:44.238: W/System.err(28802):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2115)
08-20 18:42:44.238: W/System.err(28802):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:372)
```

What am I doing wrong!?

Comment: can you post code of how you are writong (fileoutputstream)  ?

Comment: @OmarDanisha  I'm using shared preferences to store the data after reading object, why should I use `fileoutputstream`?

Comment: @OmarDanisha Yes, you can. I solved my problem now, but please look into this example, I inspired from this link in the first place: http://www.javatips.net/api/Performance-Tweaker-master/androidCommon/src/com/asksven/android/common/utils/SharedPreferencesUtils.java

Comment: Ok i got it , It was my wrong assumption ....